# how can i call web service with its URL in c#

Tags: c#, web, service

I have a web service and windows form project that have two textboxs and a button.My web service has two parameters and it checks this values exist in database or not.So I write values to textbooks and press button.I want to call my web service and it gives answer me when I pressed button. 
But I want to call web service with its URL.
Please help me immediately..

PS: Excume me for my bad English(

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you provide some code what you have tried?

Comment: You could use the deepl.com translator or google translate to make this question a little bit more understandable.

Comment: Have a look at the HttpClient class.   You could place an instance of this class in your Form.   Googling will find you many examples of its use, including this link : https://www.dotnetperls.com/httpclient

Comment: [WebMethod]
        public bool CheckLogin(string u_name, string p_word)
        {
            DataTable dt = fillDataTable("USER_1");
            DataRow[] dr = dt.Select();
            for (int i = 0; i < dr.Count() - 1; i++)
            {
                if (dr[i]["username"].ToString() == u_name && dr[i]["password"].ToString() == p_word)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string a = textBox1.Text;
            string b = textBox2.Text;
            string urlText;
            string url = string.Format("http://localhost:2591/MyWebService.asmx/CheckLogin?u_name={0}&p_word={1}", a,b);
        }......

Comment: Thank you everyone for answers

Comment: Mark, thank you, it works:)